# Convert $16500.00 String to 16500 Integer

Tags: java, android

Im having an issue trying to convert $16500.00 String to 16500 Integer.

This is what i have at the moment but its failing with:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "[]"

The code i have is:

```
String depTest = mDepositAmount.getText().toString();
String deptest2 = Arrays.toString(depTest.replace("R", "").replace(",", "").split("."));
int dep = Integer.parseInt(deptest2);
```

Please could you help me with getting the end result to 16500. I know how to convert it to int by using Integer.parseInt its just im struggling to get the end result to be 16500 in String

Comment: `Arrays.toString` is not what you want... This turns an array containing for example 1 and 2 to the String `[1, 2]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse String to Float or Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int)

Comment: initially when i tried this i used .split(".", 2)[0]

Comment: why using `Arrays` ??

Comment: @NigamPatro: how would a *Python* solution help here? This question is tagged [tag:java]..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your original string always starts with character '$' and followed by number format?
If so try this one:

```
String org = "$16500.00";
String numbersOnly = org.substring(1);   // "16500.00"
int yourInteger = (int)(Float.parseFloat(numbersOnly));

// if you need String, convert it to String again
String integerString = Integer.toString(yourInteger);
```

Comment: @x10sion You can choose my answer then :)

Comment: yea when SO allows me, 5 min delay! will do the second i can P.S. Done

Comment: whilst this method will work, there's no validation on the first character so 12345.67 will be parsed as 2345.67. IMHO a DecimalFormat is better

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this

```
String getValue = "$16500.00";
String removeFirstCharecter = getValue.substring(1);   // "16500.00"
String [] getString = removeFirstCharecter.split("\\.");

String firstIntValue = (getString[0]); //16500
String sirstIntValue = (getString[1]); //00
```

Now you can convert `firstIntValue` **String to Integer** .

```
String getRequiredValue = Integer.toString(firstIntValue); //16500
```

Comment: This is great because it then shows me how to use the .split method! Up voted for it!

Comment: @x10sion Move ahead .

Comment: Variables should not start with capital letters in java

Comment: @LanceJava indeed indeed .Roger that

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
import java.text.*;

NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
int value = (int) nf.parse("$16500.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be happen because of **$** sign so, Just take one another Text view only for Price **16500** and other for **$** sign. then convert the Integer.parseInt(textview.getText().toString);

Comment: yea sorry, i dont know why i used the $ in the question! blonde moment, it was mean to be R. Removing the relevant text is fine, its removing the .00 that i am having an issue